# Twilio PHP connector / Cant echo twillio answer

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I'm trying to connect to the twilio for sending SMS. It was working but it stopped. After i returned from holidays.

Well SMS sending is working, but i cant echo the answer from Twilio.

I found out that my php file is working sweet on PHP 5.3 but on 5.6 it is throwing an error. So it has something to do with echoing $client but i dont know whats wrong.

Here is my code:
<?php

```
        // this line loads the library 
        require dirname(__FILE__) . "../../../includes/Services/Twilio.php";

        $account_sid = 'XXX'; 
        $auth_token = 'XXX'; 
        $client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);

        //Get the submitted data
        $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $request = json_decode($postdata);


        $mamiMobile = $request -> mamiPhone;
        $text = $request -> smsoffer;


        $client->account->messages->create(array( 
            'To' => $mamiMobile, 
            'From' => "+41798071977", //From Number from Twilio
            'Body' => $text
        ));

        //This works on php 5.3 but on 5.6 it is not working!
        echo ($client);
        ;?>
```

The Error i get in the PHP.log:

```
        [03-Mar-2016 18:18:16 Europe/Zurich] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Method Services_Twilio::__toString() must return a string value in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/angular-bootstrap-admin-web-app-with-angularjs/angular/includes/php/sms_connector_twillio_offer.php on line 34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In order to echo the response from Twilio you shouldn't be echoing the `$client` itself, but the response to `$client->account->messages->create`. Why not try something like:

```
$response = $client->account->messages->create(array( 
    'To' => $mamiMobile, 
    'From' => "+41798071977", //From Number from Twilio
    'Body' => $text
));

echo ($response);
```

In answer to what changed between PHP 5.3 and 5.6, my guess is that something happened between those versions to how `$this` responds to `foreach` such that [this code](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/3ec47c0bf8bce1a25e02e007c1245405bdadb7a6/Services/Twilio/Resource.php#L123-L131) no longer works as expected.

Could you [raise a bug in the GitHub issues](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/issues) for the [twilio-php](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install) project so that someone can take a look at it? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! You were right. With $response it is working! I gonna raise a bug in the issues...